# Valid characters for URI schemes?

Tags: standards-compliance, illegal-characters, url-scheme, custom-protocol

I was thinking about [Registering an Application to a URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx) and I'd like to know, what characters are allowed in a scheme?

Some examples:

- [h323](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3508) (has numbers)

  - `h323:[<user>@]<host>[:<port>][;<parameters>]`
- [z39.50r](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2056) (has a `.` as well)

  - `z39.50r://<host>[:<port>]/<database>?<docid>[;esn=<elementset>][;rs=<recordsyntax>]`
- [paparazzi:http](http://derailer.org/paparazzi/faq) (has a `:`)

  - `paparazzi:http:[//<host>[:[<port>][<transport>]]/`

So, what characters can I fancy using?
Can we have...

- `@:TwitterUser`
- `#:HashTag`
- `$:CapitalStock`
- `?:ID-10T`

...etc., as desired, or characters in the scheme are restricted by standard?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

According to [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), Appendix A:

```
  scheme        = alpha *( alpha | digit | "+" | "-" | "." )
```

Meaning:

The scheme should start with a letter (upper or lower case), and can contains letters (still upper and lower case), number, "+", "-" and ".".

---

Note: in the case of

```
paparazzi:http:[//<host>[:[<port>][<transport>]]/
```

the scheme is only the "paparazzi" part.

Comment: I see. But there are RFCs that use numbers... Why?

Comment: Numbers are allowed in the URI scheme, but not as first character. 'a234' is valid, while '4bcd' isn't.

Comment: Do you think the fact that it will be used only as an URL protocol on Windows has any impact on the usability of other characters?

Comment: +1; What Vivien said re: the "paparazzi:" scheme. The `http://...` is passed on to the WebKit stuff. (NB: I'm the author of the app, and am also crazy and have a BNF-style document on the URL format on the site.)

Comment: `paparazzi` is akin to `mailto`: it has no hierarchy hence no `//`

Comment: Chiming in 11 years later on Camilo's question: Windows does not enforce the starts-with-alpha limitation, but because all popular browsers do, you should follow it anyway.

Answer (score 12):

The [scheme according to RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1) is defined as:

> ```
> scheme      = ALPHA *( ALPHA / DIGIT / "+" / "-" / "." )
> ```

So the scheme must begin with an alphabetic character (`A`–`Z`, `a`–`z`) and may be followed by any number of alphanumeric characters, `+`, `-`, or `.`.

Comment: Do you think using it as a Windows-only URL protocol has any impact on the characters used? If that changes anything I'd do some tests...

Answer (score 6):

Quoth [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt):

> Scheme names consist of a sequence of characters beginning with a
>      lower case letter and followed by any combination of lower case
>      letters, digits, plus ("+"), period ("."), or hyphen ("-").