# Is there any format convention in query strings?

Tags: url, formatting, query-string

I was wondering if you normally capitalise any letter in query strings, use dashes or underscores for variable names, or have any other query string naming convention. I cannot find any reference to it.

Edit: Since there seems to be no convention, are there any best practices or usual way to do it?

Comment: There's no official W3C standard of which I'm aware, if that's what you mean.  It's usually just a matter of personal/team preference.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302179/hyphen-underscore-or-camelcase-as-word-delimiter-in-uris

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't recall actually ever seeing people use dashes in parameter names in the query string. That probably shoots it down as best practice.

I would personally avoid camel case because I don't want to get into case sensitivity/insensitivity issues.

That leaves underscores, which I find is commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

There is no convention in this case at all.  URLs (in .NET at least) are case insensitive anyway.