# What is the convention for separating multiple words on a flask route?

Tags: python, flask

I have these 2 routes:

```
api.add_resource(X, "/<string:stage>/api/sales/by-type")
api.add_resource(Y, "/<string:stage>/api/sales/filters/by-type")
```

Should it be `/by_type` or `/by-type`? `/by/type` would be weird because `/by` would be a route by itself, which makes no sense. Can't find any docs about it.

Comment: Your question strikes me as more of a API design issue rather than being a Flask related convention.
That being said, please have a look at this question => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302179/hyphen-underscore-or-camelcase-as-word-delimiter-in-uris.

It seems to address the larger design issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@nitul was right, it's about API design in general, but **hyphens** are commonly used in urls even it's not standard or official but seen as the best practice, seo friendly and urls are more elegant and pretty.

in other hand, i would like to drew your attention about some particular/extra parameters in urls like **filters**, **sorting** and **pagination**, it does more sens to use them as  extra arguments `?type=TYPE` along with your base/canonical url `/<string:stage>/api/sales`  because the two routes you mentioned are logically the same at the end. Have a look at this good post https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/api-design/REST-API-Design-Filtering-Sorting-and-Pagination/ it elaborates more the topic with good patterns to adopt. that's been said, you'll need only one route :

```
api.add_resource(X, "/<string:stage>/api/sales")
```

and then depending on extra arguments eg: `?type=TYPE` in the url you return the appropriate set of objects and this way your API are more compact (you avoid redundancy) and maintainable and extensible.

and as bonus, since you are using `Flask` and depending on your need (if any), think of **Custom URL Converter** (this topic https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/views.html#custom-converters will help you)