# Multiple get methods in .net core 3.1 web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, webapi

I am trying to create a very basic controller with three get methods
Below are the three uri's for them

1. GET /movies - gets all movies.
2. GET /movies?name={name}` - finds all movies matching the specified name
3. Get /Movies/{Id} - Find movie By Id

My code for the controller is as below:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MoviesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMoviesService moviesService;

    public MoviesController(IMoviesService moviesService)
    {
        this.moviesService = moviesService;
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var result = await moviesService.GetMoviesAsync();
        return Ok(result);
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetByName([FromQuery(Name = "name")] string name)
    {
        var result = await moviesService.GetMoviesByNameAsync(name);
        return Ok(result);
    }

    [HttpGet("{Id}", Name = "GetById")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(Guid Id)
    {
        var result = await moviesService.GetMovieById(Id);
        return Ok(result);
    }       

}
```

When I send the request to GetById by `api/movies/31234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef` then it works
but for `api/movies` and `api/movies?name=Test` I get below error:

> The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: MoviesController.Get and MoviessController.GetByName

Can anyone please suggest me what is the best way to implement such scenario in web API .net core 3.1 considering best practises?

Answer (score 31):

You'd be better off changing your urls to something like:
`api/movies/getByName/{name}` and `api/movies/getById/{id}`.

Then:

1. GET `/movies` - gets all movies
2. GET `/movies/getByName/{name}` - finds all movies matching the
   specified name
3. GET `/movies/getById/{id}` - finds a movie by Id

When adding other actions, you can also add the action name to the route, which will help you avoid `The request matched multiple endpoints.`

Here is a demo:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    return Ok();
}

[HttpGet("getByName/{name}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByName(string name)
{
    return Ok();
}

[HttpGet("getById/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(Guid Id)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your `Get` and `GetByName` actions have no attribute route provided for them and are both matched to "api/Movies". In order to resolve that you need to add a route template to at least one of those actions, too.

A possible solution is:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var result = await moviesService.GetMoviesAsync();
    return Ok(result);
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("{name}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByName([FromRoute] string name)
{
    var result = await moviesService.GetMoviesByNameAsync(name);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Note that here the the url for movies with a specific name is no longer */movies?name={name}*, but */movies/{name}*.

If you absolutely wish to keep the URL */movies?name={name}* you can merge the `Get` and `GetByName` actions in a single action that accepts a query string parameter `name` and based on its value execute your logic.

Comment: When use `/movies/xxxx`,it will get `The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: 

WebAPI.Controllers.MoviesController.GetById (WebAPI)
WebAPI.Controllers.MoviesController.GetByName (WebAPI)`

Answer (score 4):

@Nishant, your is almost good with some minor changes. Below is the working solution. The comments are inline within the code.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MoviesController : ControllerBase
{
    //GET /movies - gets all movies.
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    //GET /movies/name={name}` - finds all movies matching the specified name
    [HttpGet("{name}")]  //added the route
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetByName(string name) // modified the input parameter
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    //Get /Movies/{Id} - Find movie By Id
    [HttpGet("{Id:guid}", Name = "GetById")] //added the input type
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(Guid Id)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

}
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple methods, keeping in mind that at the beginning of the controller you initialized the way to call the controller methods, like this:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
```

....
each action or method must specify [action] and name

```
 [Route("[action]", Name = "GetPersona")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetPersona(int Id)
    {
        bool ok = false;
        string mensaje = "Sin Datos";
        var data = await Task.Run(() => _repositoryPersonas.GetPersona(Id));
        if (data != null)
        {
            mensaje = "ok";
            ok = true;
        }
        return Ok(new { data, ok, mensaje });
    }


    [Route("[action]", Name = "ObtenerPersonas")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ObtenerPersonas(int Ids)
    {
        bool ok = false;
        string mensaje = "Sin Datos";
        var data = await Task.Run(() => _repositoryPersonas.GetPersona(Ids));
        if (data != null)
        {
            mensaje = "ok";
            ok = true;
        }
        return Ok(new { data, ok, mensaje });
    }
```

`route1`https://localhost:44376/api/Personas/GetPersona?Id=1
`route2`https://localhost:44376/api/Personas/ObtenerPersonas?Id=1

Answer (score 2):

I use this

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByName([FromQuery(Name = "name")] string name)
{
    var result = await moviesService.GetMoviesByNameAsync(name);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: This is perfect answer when needs to call by action, without depend only on HTTP verbs

Answer (score 0):

Drawing on the accepted answer from 'Yiyi You' I would make slight changes in accordance with the [accepted answer (and others) to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18450653/1255622). Using hyphens will make you urls more 'crawlable' by search engines if it is a public api.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    return Ok();
}

[HttpGet("get-by-name/{name}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByName(string name)
{
    return Ok();
}

[HttpGet("get-by-id/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(Guid Id)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:- Create a fucntion with api end point and query param
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkR5m.png)

Step 2:- Hit the below url in browser (for GET methods)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pShkZ.png)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your answer, then select it and click the code block button.