# Parameter with hyphen in Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, .net-4.8

I want to follow [proper URL convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18450653/11436180) and use hyphen as word delimiter: `/api/books?author-id=3`

But property names with hyphen are not supported in C#. How can I bind `AuthorId` to `author-id` in .NET Framework 4.8?

As an example, consider this URL: `/api/books?authorid=3`

It maps to the method below.

```cs
[RoutePrefix("api/books")]
public class BooksController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBooks([FromUri] GetBooksParameters getBooksParameters)
    {
        var authorId = getBooksParameters.AuthorId;
        // ...
    }
}

public class GetBooksParameters
{
    public int? AuthorId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Property names with `-` aren't supported in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for   url ..../api/books?author-id=3&genre-id=5 . It works for all net versions

```
 [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBooks()
    {
       var parameters = GetBooksParameters(HttpContext);
    // ...
   }

    [NonAction]
    private BooksParameters GetBooksParameters(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var parameters = new BooksParameters();

        var queryString = httpContext.Request.QueryString.Value;

        foreach (string item in queryString.Split('&'))
        {
            string[] parts = item.Replace("?", "").Split('=');

            switch (parts[0])
            {
                case "author-id":
                    parameters.AuthorId = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]);
                    break;
                case "book-id":
                    parameters.BookId = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return parameters;
    }
```

parameters

```
 public class BooksParameters
 {
        public int? AuthorId { get; set; }
        public int? BookId { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: This is not very scalable for multiple methods...

Comment: @Tvde1 There is nothing about multiple methods in the question. It is not a free coding resource and  I am not going to spend the whole day creating a library. It is just a hint for PO.