# POST request: How do I have 1 [FromBody] class/object argument + 1 IFormFile argument in the same request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am looking to receive 1 `CNCTask` class object from the body, but I also need to transfer a file in the same `POST` request. I have written out my `POST` route definition as:

```
[HttpPost("TaskUpload")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public async Task<ActionResult<CNCTask>> Post([FromBody] CNCTask task, IFormFile file)
```

With my route defined as such, I just don't get how I will even transfer the file (e.g. when testing from Postman). A file would usually be sent in the body (I think ?), but if I already have my `CNCTask` object being selected by the `[FromBody]`, how do I negotiate this file transfer as well ?

I'm quite confused as to how to send both the class object and the file. Any tips would be appreciated.

## EDIT

### `text` body request that only includes a `CNCTask` object

```
{
  "description":"truc",
  "completion":24,
  "machine":{
    "hostname":"some host",
    "port": 1234
  }
}
```

### `form-data` body request that includes the full `Payload` (`CNCTask` + `IFormFile`)

[image: Form-data]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload files and JSON in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367602/upload-files-and-json-in-asp-net-core-web-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was tested using a Postman and Visual studio.

You have to create a model class

```
public class CNCTask
{
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Completion { get; set; }
        public Machine Machine { get; set; }
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}

public class Machine
{
        public string Hostname { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
}
```

action

```
[HttpPost("TaskUpload")]
public async Task<ActionResult<CNCTask>> Post(CNCTask model)
```

and you  can test it using postman

[image]

Comment: Right, thanks for that. When actually testing my request in Postman, how would I want to build my client-side request? Also to note is that `CNCTask` itself also has a parameter of type `IMachine` (class object).

Comment: @JetsON Try  both  [FromBody] and [FromForm] attributes if you test from postman,  and add multipart/form-data header

Comment: Would you recommmend sticking to this custom model or using a `JObject` like shown in this answer ? This looks pretty simple to use. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37298083/16938804

Comment: @JetsON I would never use JObject since it is untyped. You will have to convert using json serializer to c# . As a matter of fact ,  all data  is arriving as JObject to action.   But when you  put a concrete class as  input parameter, C#  convert this for you automaticaly. I don't see what you can gain , since you will have to write some extra code. And plus it is a very bad programming style. Nobody ever uses it. Only in a very special cases where there is no any another way. Do you still have any problem?

Comment: @JetsON you can even use httprequest to get input parameters . See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69406588/11392290. But why do this if there are much easier and clear ways.

Comment: My issue is that I have an object within an object. My `CNCTask` object contains a custom `Machine` class, so I'm struggling to figure out how I will properly extract data properly from my body's `form-data` and build the `Machine` object then build the `CNCTask` object. Bit confused... Right now, I've coded it out as ```IFormFile File = payload.File; CNCTask Task = payload.Task;``` but I don't think the API will really extract the body `form-data` properly with that...

Comment: @The most classes are custom. How do you submit it ? using form and submit button or something else? Could you post your full view pls?

Comment: I'm not using a submit button, nor is there any view at all. This is just a Web API that will be used by a different service. I'm trying to send my POST requests right now, it works with just the `CNCTask` (as a `text` body) but I cannot get it to work with both an `IFormFile` and `CNCTask` (as a `form-data` body, so that I can include the file). My `CNCTask` object contains a JSON object of its own, that might be why my `form-data` request doesn't work... Any ideas ?

Comment: I've added clear examples to my original post as an edit.

Comment: @JetsON Thank you I updated my answer. This code was tested and is working properly

Answer (score 0):

You can retrive form data as follows

```
var formdata = Request.Form["formdata"];
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelEntity>(formdata);
```

And write your controller this way

```
public async Task<ActionResult<CNCTask>> Post(IFormFile file)
{
    var formdata = Request.Form["formdata"];
    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InitialDemandEntity>(formdata);
            ...
}
```