# Is there a standard for protocol names in URIs?

Tags: regex, uri

Is there a standard for protocol names in URIs e.g. http: or file:? I'm trying to develop a regex that will detect if a URI starts with a protocol name but I'm not sure what characters are allowed there.

Comment: Aaaaand after answering I discover a duplicate, [which I've apparently also answered, albeit slightly differently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641722/valid-characters-for-uri-schemes/3641775#3641775)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RFC 3986, section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1) has the grammar:

```
scheme      = ALPHA *( ALPHA / DIGIT / "+" / "-" / "." )
```

Which means protocol names must start with a letter, and can be followed by any number of letters, numbers, or `+`, `-` or `.` symbols. Protocol names are case-insensitive (that is, `HTTP` and `http` should be treated the same), but generally they should be canonicalized to lowercase forms (so `HTTP` should become `http`).

Comment: One more small piece of the puzzle, the scheme component delimiter (":") is defined here https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3

Comment: +1 And if you're lazy, check out my article "[Regular Expression URI Validation](http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html)" for all the associated RFC3986 regex code snippets.