# NSWidgetExtensionContext openURL Swift

Tags: ios, swift, widget, openurl

I have been attempting to implement a button to open my iOS app from its widget. I realize this issue has been beaten to death on the forums but I cannot find explanation with the specific error I am receiving. Perhaps some of you more experienced iOS developers can shed some light on this.

I am developing an update to one of my iOS apps for iOS 10 using XCode 8.1 and Swift 2.

Code for my widget's button:
[image]

URL scheme added to the widget's info.plist:
[image]

The runtime error I receive when pressing the OpenApp button:

```
AppWidget[11872:3577323] __55-[_NCWidgetExtensionContext openURL:completionHandler:]_block_invoke failed: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "(null)"
```

// Note: app name has been substituted with appropriate generics.

Comment: Have you added "AppName" to URL Types in your app settings?

Comment: I have done so as shown in the info.plist screenshot above

Comment: Did you find the solution to your problem? I also have registered my url-scheme and my extension is trying to open my app, but I only see `[_NCWidgetExtensionContext openURL:completionHandler:]_block_invoke failed: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "(null)"` in the console. Maybe it's the same issue?!?

Answer (score 11):

I often find the [OS Status lookup](http://www.osstatus.com) site pretty useful to infer details from errors. An OS error with code `-10814` is a `kLSApplicationNotFoundErr`, which describes the scenario when:

> No application in the Launch Services database matches the input criteria.

It sounds like your application has not been properly registered with the system as a consumer of the URL scheme you are using. Have you double-double (double!) checked that the bundle identifier and URL scheme match? Have you verified that your app can be launched with the URL from Safari?

Comment: I am having the kind of same error as the author of this article here. I tribble checked my bundle_identifier und url scheme and everything... still... I am getting an -50 error (didn't find a proper one from the link you posted :( )
Do you have any other ideas for me?

Comment: "double-double (double!) checked that the bundle identifier and URL scheme match" (c)

Answer (score 5):

URL scheme should added to the main app's info.plist, not the widget's.

Answer (score 4):

To open the Containing App from Todays Extension:

```
let myAppUrl = URL(string: "main-screen:")!
extensionContext?.open(myAppUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
    if (!success) {
        print("error: failed to open app from Today Extension")
    }
})
```

You also need to add the following lines to the application's info.plist (open as a source code):

```
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.mikitamanko.bubblewrap</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>main-screen</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

right after the

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
```

Here's the [complete guide](http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/02/15/swift-how-to-create-ios-today-extension-and-share-data-with-containing-app/) how to open the app or share Users Defaults with Extension and the containing app.

Answer (score 0):

Also you should check if you are using any not allowed character for your url scheme.
Maybe it is not your case but I was using this and it was wrong:

```
my_AppName
```

instead this finally worked :)

```
myAppName
```

as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3641782/2946782), the scheme must begin with alphanumeric character and it can contain only `alphanumeric characters`, `+`, `-` and `.`