# How to force safari to open in full screen mode instead of Split Screen on iPad?

Tags: swift

When I want to open a URL from my application in Safari on iPad,

It will be open Safari in split screen mode:

[image: iPad with split screen by Safari]

Is there anyway to prevent split screen and force Safari to open in full size mode?

```
let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")!

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:]) { _ in}
}
```

Comment: Can you try keyword external like this in url ? ```external:https://www.google.com```

Comment: @MandeepGill, doesn't work: external:https://www.google.com: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "(null)"

Comment: Please follow this stackoverflow post if still have issue then i will find check other solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40440169/nswidgetextensioncontext-openurl-swift

Comment: If you try your script in playground with external keyword then you can see difference so just have to configure settings in your application so iOS can allow to open external urls.

Comment: @MandeepGill, What settings should I configure?