# Starting an Activity from WebView click causes "Webpage not available"

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to start another activity from html webview.So i have one working link but second link is not working. And it says 
"**Webpage not available**"

```
public class acilisbir extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView myBrowser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_acilisbir);

    myBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.anasayfagetir);
    myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/anasayfa.html");
}

 private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
//This link is work
if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("Navigation://OpenNativeScreen")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(acilisbir.this,AnaEkran.class));
                finish();
                return true;
             //But this is not
            }else if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("activity_buy://Buy")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(acilisbir.this,Buy.class));
                finish();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**I'add to my** `manifest`

```
<activity android:name="Buy" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <data android:scheme="activity_buy" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**Html link code**

```
<INPUT TYPE="test" value="Test" onClick="window.location='Navigation://OpenNativeScreen'">
<INPUT TYPE="buycr" value="Buycr" onClick="window.location='activity_buy://Buy'">
```

here the link **targeting the Buy Activity** is not working.I have no error in android studio.But its not starting the BuyActivity when the link is clicked.

Comment: hie! ^_^ please try @julianCDC's answer and reply i think this is the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax) your scheme must not contains any other caracters that letters or "+", "-", ".".

Try renaming activity_buy://Buy to activitybuy://Buy.

Comment: Than you so much.You saved me big time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3641782/1283715) and According to [**RFC 2396**](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt),

**Appendix A:** URI scheme shall be follow this:

```
scheme        = alpha *( alpha | digit | "+" | "-" | "." )
```

**Then Replace this:**

```
url.equalsIgnoreCase("activity_buy://Buy")
"window.location='activity_buy://Buy'"
```

**With:**

```
url.equalsIgnoreCase("activity.buy://Buy")
"window.location='activity.buy://Buy'"
```

- Please consider to **up-vote** JulianCDC [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53215226/1283715) for mentioning reference for expected issue.

**Update**

You may use `Uri.pasre(url)` instead of `url.equalsIgnoreCase`

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
String scheme = uri.getScheme();
String host = uri.getHost();
switch (scheme){
    case "Navigation":
        handleNavigation(host);
        break;
    case "activity.buy":
        handleActivityActions(host);
        break;
}

private void handleNavigation(String host) {
    // do other stuff
    if ("OpenNativeScreen".equals(host)) {
        startActivity(new Intent(acilisbir.this, AnaEkran.class));
        finish();
    }
}

private void handleActivityActions(String host) {
    // do other stuff
    if ("Buy".equals(host)) {
        startActivity(new Intent(acilisbir.this,Buy.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately my reputation point it's not enough yet for that.But i will when it's enough.I'm following this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791482/start-activity-intent-on-clicking-text-inside-webview and i didn't know about  to Appendix.Thank you to.